# dynamic html javascript menu active selection

Tags: javascript, html, menu, html-lists

I found this script and I understand why it won't work with my menu as it is but cannot figure out how to get it to work

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
        var currentPHP = document.location.href.substr(i+1);
        $("ul#menu li a").removeClass('current');
        $("ul#menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']").addClass('current');
  });
</script>

<nav>
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="gallery.php">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="location.php">Location</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var currentPHP = document.location.pathname.replace(/.+\//i, "")
  $("ul.menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']").parent().addClass("current");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the ul by it's id: `ul#menu`. Select it by the class name: `ul.menu`. You are also adding and removing the current class from a and not li. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
    var currentPHP = document.location.href.substr(i+1);
    $("ul.menu li")
       .removeClass('current')
       .has("a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']")
       .addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: Considering that the first `li` always has the `current` class ... hmm nice.

Comment: @Gerard: It removes the current class from all li's and than narrows the selection down to the one that has an a tag with the desired href, which than gets the current class.

Comment: I understand. Didn't know about the existence of the `has` function in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want the class to be on the `<li>` not the `<a>` elements? You're adding it to the anchors themselves. Try:

```
$("ul.menu li").removeClass('current');
$("ul.menu li a[href^='"+currentPHP+"']").parent().addClass('current');
```

(You were also selecting by id not class, as jazZRo pointed out - edited to use class)